# Is it OK that I submitted sitemaps for www and no-www?

Tags: google, sitemap

I have submitted two sitemaps of the same website. One for www and one for no the www version of my website.

Should I delete one of the 2 sitemaps on the URL with redirect? In that case I would leave the sitemap to version no-www.

Is anything else I should do?

Comment: You should not have both versions of your site available. You will get into duplicate content issues. Chose one, and redirect the other to it. You should only have one sitemap as well and it should reference URLs of the site you chose. As well, it really is not necessary at all to have a sitemap unless your site is extremely large or has content behind a login or paywall or your links cannot be crawled for some reason. So if your site is new, don't bother with a sitemap. It is a waste of time and effort.

Answer (score 2):

Create a sitemap containing URLs for the non-www version of the site that you want indexed. Anyone who accesses the www version should get redirected to the non-www version of the same URL.

If your server is apache with mod_rewrite installed, you can modify your server configuration so it also contains the following lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

That way, the redirect will happen very quickly if someone requests the www version of your site.